# User can't access some desktop files

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

A user on a Windows 7 Pro PC in a Windows 2003 network can access all her files, except for a few on her desktop (which is stored in a network share), which have their icon semi-transparent with a cross. Other files on the desktop can be accessed normally.

Permissions on the server seem alright: she is the owner of all the desktop files and has full control. I can open the blocked files on the server, so they aren't corrupt or anything.

No other user has any issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like it could be a fault with Offline Files, have you tried making sure it is working as it should be or disabling it entirely? http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/07/turn-on-off-offline-files-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, it sounds like these are shortcuts to files on a network drive that are inaccessible from her machine (we don't know why) but are accessible from yours. Remap the network drive on her machine, and the shortcuts should work again.

Comment: Actually these aren't shortcuts. The Desktop is mapped to a network share at the GP level.